# Is onReceive a proper method to do caller permission check?

Tags: android, security, ipc

Is calling into checkCallingPermsision() API in onReceive method of a Broadcast receiver a proper method to check the caller app's permission?

onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)

Does the context passed to onReceive above have access to the calling app UID/PID, so we can just call into context.checkCallingPermission to make a proper judgement about the caller's permission?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inside a broadcast-receiver `onReceive` is fine to check for the permission. That context will have access to the same things that your activities or services do.

Remember of course, that you cannot ask for permission there. Asking must be inside an Activity/Fragment

Comment: Thanks Budius. Would you please give me an example of what you mean by the check needs to be part of an activity/fragment? Why can't I just have it inside onReceive?

Comment: oh are you talking about implementing the ask for permission on caller app side? If yes, I agree.